# Enthalpy of the reaction between hydrogen and oxygen

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy

> The reaction between hydrogen and oxygen to yield water vapor has
>   $\Delta H^\circ = \pu{- 484 kJ}$. How much $pV$ work is done, and what is the value of $\Delta E$ in kilojoules for the reaction of $\pu{0.50 mol}$ of $\ce{H2}$ with $\pu{0.25 mol}$ of $\ce{O2}$ at atmospheric pressure if the volume change is $-\pu{5.6L}?$
>
> $$\ce{2H2(g) + O2(g) -> 2H2O(g)} \qquad \Delta H^\circ = \pu{- 484 kJ}$$

I use the formula $\Delta E=\Delta H - p\Delta V$ to determine $\Delta E.$ However, when determining the enthalpy, the solutions manual does this:

> $$\Delta H = \frac{\pu{-121 kJ}}{\pu{0.50 mol}~\ce{H2}}$$

Where does the $-121$ come from? From my understanding, since there are two moles $\ce{H2}$, $\Delta H$ should be $-\pu{242 kJ}$. Or do we take into account all four hydrogen atoms? That would give us $\pu{-484 kJ}/4 = -\pu{121 kJ}.$

Comment: Is ∆E or ∆H change in enthalpy?

Comment: $\Delta H$ is change in enthalpy

Answer (score 3):

The confusion is partly caused by careless use of quantities and units. The value $H = -484\ \mathrm{kJ}$ denotes an enthalpy. However, what is actually meant is the enthalpy *per one mole;* i.e. the molar enthalpy $H_{\mathrm m} = -484\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$.

In the definition of the molar reaction enthalpy, the ‘per mole’ does not refer to any particular substance in the equation. Instead it refers to the entire reaction as a whole. Therefore, the reaction must be specified for which this quantity applies. In this case, the enthalpy of $484\ \mathrm{kJ}$ is released when $2\ \mathrm{mol}$ of hydrogen gas react with $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of oxygen gas to form $2\ \mathrm{mol}$ of *gaseous* water: 
$$\ce{2H2(g) + O2(g) -> 2H2O(g)}\qquad\Delta H^\circ = -484\ \mathrm{kJ}$$
(By way of comparison, the corresponding value for *liquid* water is about $-572\ \mathrm{kJ}$.)

Thus, the molar enthalpy relating to the amount of hydrogen is
$$\frac{\Delta H^\circ}{n(\ce{H2})}=\frac{-484\ \mathrm{kJ}}{2\ \mathrm{mol}}=\frac{-242\ \mathrm{kJ}}{1\ \mathrm{mol}}=-242\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$$
i.e. the released enthalpy per $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ of hydrogen gas is $242\ \mathrm{kJ}$.

However, the given question is asking about $n(\ce{H2}) = 0.50\ \mathrm{mol}$ of hydrogen (and accordingly $n(\ce{O2}) = 0.25\ \mathrm{mol}$ of oxygen). The corresponding enthalpy is
$$\begin{align}
0.5\ \mathrm{mol}\times\frac{\Delta H^\circ}{n(\ce{H2})}&= 0.5\ \mathrm{mol}\times\frac{-484\ \mathrm{kJ}}{2\ \mathrm{mol}}\\[6pt]
&= 0.5\ \mathrm{mol}\times\frac{-242\ \mathrm{kJ}}{1\ \mathrm{mol}}\\[6pt]
&= 0.5\ \mathrm{mol}\times -242\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}\\[6pt]
&= -121\ \mathrm{kJ}
\end{align}$$